# Prevent WP WebBrowser from over scrolling

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, windows-phone, webbrowser-control

Is there any way that I can prevent a user from over scrolling the WebBrowser control in a Windows Phone application? I am revering to what happens when you have scrolled to the limit of the page but then pull it further and a white bar then appears on the side until you release your finger.

Comment: Share your code, so that we could find what went wrong and how make it work right!

Comment: There is no code! Over scrolling the standard behavior of a WebBrowser component and I want a way to disable but have not managed to find any appropriate settings or existing code to do so and am thus posting a question here asking if anyone knows if it is even possible.

Comment: Does this [technique](http://www.jamescroft.co.uk/blog/windows-phone-dev/preventing-bounce-scrolling-in-windows-phone-html5-games/) help at all?

Comment: @NeilTurner I'll try it but it will be complicated because I would first have to figure out how to apply that css to every webpage loaded. This project is for a type of webbrowser that obviously does not display predetermined pages.

Comment: @NeilTurner It probably won't work because according to IE documentation this completely disables panning which is something I need, I just need it to stop that effect where it overscrolls and then bounces back.

Comment: Ok, I thought it was worth a try.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Cordova Framework. You have to add below in your c# main class file

```
 public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.CordovaView.DisableBouncyScrolling = true;
        //Splash_Screen();
    }
```

use Cordova latest 2.5+